# GDB commands stop execution if previous command fails

Tags: c, linux, gdb

In GDB want to print values of all pointers in an array on hitting a breakpoint. There may be array elements with value as 0x0.

Ex:

```
arr[] = {0x0, 0x5cb04, 0x5510, 0x0, 0x5c84}

(gdb) info b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x1234 in fun1 at file1.c:200
        p arr
        p *arr[0]
        p *arr[1]
        p *arr[2]
        p *arr[3]
        c
```

But GDB fails to print values of *arr[1], *arr[2], *arr[3], coz

> *arr[0] hits the error
>
> "Cannot access memory at address 0x0" .

Is there any solution or workaround to this problem?

Comment: You want to print `arr[0]` to get the element value not `*arr[0]` dereference element value, right?

Comment: i want to dereference the element value. is there a if condition that can help here?

Comment: i've a array of pointers , in this case arr[0] will give me 0x0, arr[1] will give me 0x5cb04. i want to print values at 0x5cb04, so i'm doing *arr[1]

Comment: you mean `p (arr[0]) ? *arr[0] : "null"` ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker thanks it works. post this as the answer.

Comment: i checked http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_6.html but didnt find this info. can you please provide any better link.

Comment: @dhanlin : I included a link in my answer that has more detail on the print command specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gdb print command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Data.html#Data) can use any valid [expression](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Expressions.html#Expressions), so you could do something like :

```
p (arr[0]) ? *arr[0] : "null"
```